# A challenge for you SQL lovers out there

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm new to the working world an am fresh out of varsity. i started working an am creating a few reports via SQL reporting services as part of my training.

Here is quite a challenge that I am stuck at. Please help me finish this query. Here is how it goes!

- There are several employees in the employee_table that each have unique identifier known as the emp_id
- There is a time_sheet table that consists of several activities AND THE HOURS FOR EACH ONE for the employees and references them via emp_id. Each activity has a TIMESHEET_DATE that corresponds to the day all the activities were submitted(once a month). There are several activities with the same date because all those activities were submitted on the same day.
- And there is a leave table that references the employees via emp_id. In the leave table, there is a column for the amount of days they took off and the starting day (Leave_FROM) of the leave.

I must create a parameter where the user inputs the month (easy peasy)...

Now in the report, column 1 must have their name (easy), column 2 must have their totals hours for the specified month (HOURS) and column 3 must show how many days they took leave for that month specified.

It can be tricky, not everybody has a entry in the leavetable, but everybody has got activities in the Time_Sheet table.

Here is what I have gotten so far from a query, but its not really helping me.

Unfortunately, I cannot upload pictures, so here is a link

http://imageshack.com/a/img822/8611/5czv.jpg

Oh yea, my flavor of SQL is SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different things you need to attack here.

First is getting information from the `employee_table`, regardless of what is in the other two tables. To do this, I would `left join` on both of the tables.

Your second battle is, now since you have multiple rows in your `time_sheet` table, you are going to get a record for every `time_sheet` record. That is not what you want. You can fix this by using a [SUM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) Aggregate and a `GROUP BY` clause.

Next is the issue that you are going to have when nothing exists in leave table and it is returning NULL. If you add an `ISNULL(value,0)` around your leave table field, it will return 0 when no records exist on that table (for that employee).

Here is what your query should look like (not exactly sure on table/column naming):

I changed the query to use temp tables, so totals are stored separately. Since the temp tables will hold 0 for employees that don't have time/leave, you can do an inner join on your final query. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server) out for more information on temp tables.

```
SELECT e.emp_id, ISNULL(SUM(ts.Hours),0)[Time]
INTO #TotalTime
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN time_sheet ts ON e.emp_id = ts.emp_id
GROUP BY e.emp_id

SELECT e.emp_id, ISNULL(SUM(l.days),0) [LeaveTime]
INTO #TotalLeave
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN leaveTable l ON e.emp_id=l.emp_id
GROUP BY e.emp_id

SELECT e.Emp_Id,Time,LeaveTime FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN #TotalTime t ON e.Emp_Id=t.Emp_Id 
INNER JOIN #TotalLeave l ON e.Emp_Id=l.Emp_Id 

DROP TABLE #TotalLeave,#TotalTime
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3e74/1/0)

Comment: Thanks, it definitely got me further than what I was before..... But please check the link attached to my screenshot, for some reason, im getting insane leave days. Emp 8 ony has 1 day of leave in the LeaveTable, and Emp 2 only has 5 days.

http://imageshack.com/a/img22/3031/fq6o.jpg

Comment: And also, for some reason, the Total_Hours are multiplying by the amount of entries in the leaveTable. Emp 2 only has 70 hours in timesheet, but on the screenshot it shows 280 hours!! I assume its multiplying because Emp 2 has 4 entries in leaveTable (4*70 = 280)

Comment: That was my fault, I didn't think that through. I changed my query and added the sql fiddle. This should take care of that issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

`Left join` the leave table, if nobody took leave you won't get  any results.